# Column chart with different widths of columns

Tags: c#, charts

I'm trying to create a column chart that has columns with diffrent widths.

Is it possible to create a chart like that with the chart control or should I look for a library that supports it?

[image]

Comment: Try to modify the [DataPoint width](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.it/2010/09/how-to-set-change-chart-datapoint.html)

Comment: This works for all the columns, while I need each column to have a diffrent width - e.g. Column1 has a width of 3, Column2 has a width of 10 etc.

Comment: loop through the columns and with a switch set the different widths

Comment: I tried it, but there are no changes on the chart, the width remains the same on all columnes.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `MarkerSize` property on each `DataPoint` individually

Comment: I tried looping through all the points and setting the MarkerSize (each time a diffrent value), but  there were no changes on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Area type chart like this:

[image]

Set it up

```
Series s1 = chart1.Series.Add("S1");
s2.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area;

ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX.Minimum = 0;

AddArea(chart1, s2, 12, 53, Color.SlateBlue);
AddArea(chart1, s2, 32, 63, Color.Firebrick);
AddArea(chart1, s2, 22, 23, Color.SlateBlue);
AddArea(chart1, s2, 62, 33, Color.Goldenrod);
AddArea(chart1, s2, 12, 33, Color.PaleVioletRed);
```

and add points like this:

```
int AddArea(Chart chart, Series s, double x, double y, Color color)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[s.ChartArea];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    if (s.Points.Count == 0) s.Points.AddXY(ax.Minimum, ay.Minimum);
    DataPoint dp0 = s.Points.Last();
    int p1 = s.Points.AddXY(dp0.XValue, y);
    s.Points.AddXY(dp0.XValue + x, y);
    s.Points.Last().Color = color;
    s.Points.AddXY(dp0.XValue + x, ay.Minimum);
    dp0.Color = color;
    s.Points.Last().Color = color;

    return p1;
}
```