# C# - Formatting Column Chart

Tags: c#, charts, alignment

Good evening everyone.

Trying to format the column chart with some data, and I've experiencing a problem.
All columns are centered at their labels. I want each column to be between the labels.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Vsb.png)

Code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Chart myChart = new Chart();
myChart.Parent = this;
myChart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 185);
myChart.Location = new Point(865, 56);
myChart.Titles.Add("Distribution of clients per time span");
ChartArea chArea = new ChartArea("clientsDistribution");
chArea.AxisX.Title = "Time span";
chArea.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont;
chArea.AxisY.Title = "Count";
chArea.AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 5;
myChart.ChartAreas.Add(chArea);
Series mySeriesOfPoint = new Series("timeSpans");
mySeriesOfPoint.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
mySeriesOfPoint.ChartArea = "clientsDistribution";
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
{
    mySeriesOfPoint.Points.AddXY(x + 9, countByTimeSpan[x]);
    mySeriesOfPoint.Points[x].Color = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
}
myChart.Series.Add(mySeriesOfPoint);
myChart.Series["timeSpans"]["PointWidth"] = "1";
```

Comment: I think this is a misleading graphics. Or iou could pick the right type: This is really about AreaChart, not column..

Comment: That's close to it, but not exactly what I want (https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/28/a3f0ef69a27617068da7b49505bee04c-full.png)

Comment: Yes, You need extra points to create rectangluar areas.. see [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932003/column-chart-with-different-widths-of-columns/39195082#39195082)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks!
https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/2/28/df22a856130ff7131056d30dd55bce28-full.png

Comment: If you found that post useful you may want to consider upvoting it..

Comment: Did it, now it's recorded but publicly displayed post score didn't changed cause my reputation is low.

Comment: Ah, right; sorry. I would have been able to close this post as a duplicate but now we need to wait til someone else comes along .. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you could increase the `chArea.AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0.5;` . Maybe try setting it to 1.

**OR**

You could try using chart alignment options:

> **AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel()**   Aligns data points along the X axis
>   using their axis labels. Applicable when multiple series are indexed
>   and their X-values are strings.
>
> **AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel(String)**     Aligns data points from different
>   series along the X axis using their axis labels. The specified series
>   in the chart are aligned using an ascending sort order.
>
> **AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel(PointSortOrder)**     Aligns data points using
>   their axis labels. All series in the chart are aligned, using the
>   specified sort order.
>
> **AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel(String, PointSortOrder)**     Aligns data points
>   using their axis labels.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.aligndatapointsbyaxislabel?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: chArea.AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0.5; makes it in the way I want it, but numbers on X axis are double, what I don't want to see.

Comment: AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel() throws an exception that calls that I must set XValueIndexed for all series to TRUE or use not null XValue for every point

Comment: managed to get rid of that exception, but I didn't get what I expected to